# Material-UI React: Global theme override for Paper component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a React app built with the latest Material-UI component library.

I use many instances of the `Paper` component. I want to apply margins and padding to all them at once, without manually repeating this process for every instance.

I looked up the [Material-UI documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/themes/#customizing-all-instances-of-a-component-type) on the topic, and from what I can tell, the following code *should* correctly override how Paper looks:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        Paper: {
            root: {
                padding: '10px',
                marginBottom: '10px',
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Below is where overridden style *should* apply:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    {/* ... */}
    <Paper>
        Content goes here
    </Paper>
    {/* ... */}
</ThemeProvider>
```

But the overridden values aren't being applied. Any suggestions as to what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: For MUI5 (the latest MUI library), please see post by @G M. Essentially, you should use `createTheme` function and the expected input has a much different structure than the depreciated `createMuiTheme`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in your App.js add (please note `MuiPaper` and not `Paper`):

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiPaper: {
      root: {
        padding: '10px',
        marginBottom: '10px'
      },
    },
  }
});
```

at the same `App.js` file, wrap your HTML:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div className="App">
          <YourComponent1 />      
          <YourComponent2 />
          ...
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

this way, any `Paper` component rendered by React will have your CSS.

BTW, I created [MUI schematics](https://github.com/andriy101/mui-schematics) module which adds Material UI support, generates several Material UI components automatically and adds general theme rules in `App.js`. You are welcome to take a look / try it...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use your CssBaseline component if you're already using it for global reset...all depends on how you're structuring your theme.

Eg below is from the Mui docs:
<CssBaseline.js>

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      '@global': {
        html: {
          WebkitFontSmoothing: 'auto',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
      

 // ...
return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    {children}
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```

You can get more details from the docs here [using CssBaseline to inject global theme overrides.](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/)

Answer (score 1):

`createMuiTheme` is depreciated **in MUI5**.

Instead, you should be using `createTheme` as follows:

```
export const myTheme = createTheme({
    components:{
       MuiPaper:{ 
          defaultProps:{
             sx:{
                padding: '10px',
                marginBottom: '10px'
             }
          }
       }
    }
})
```

Additionally, make sure that you wrap your app in the `Theme` component and add the `CssBaseline` component:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';
import { myTheme } from './themes/my-theme';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';

<ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
   <CssBaseline />
   <MyApp/>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Here is the [official documentation for MUI5](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem.

The internal component name used for CSS is `MuiPaper`, not simply `Paper`. The following produces the desired result:

```
overrides: {
    MuiPaper: {
        root: {
            padding: '10px',
            marginBottom: '10px',
        },
    },
},
```